# Find special characters inside of pre tag and wrap in div tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using `file_get_contents();` to display the output of a files on pages. The outputs are typically over 15,000 lines of code all wrapped in-between one `pre` tag.

Here is an example of the output I'm receiving:

```
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1.  SOME TEXT HERE
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Some stuff
    all here


  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    2. MORE TEXT HERE
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Random Stuff Here

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    3. TITLE HERE
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    More random stuff
    they are all different lengths as well
```

This is the general layout which goes into the hundreds. I want to wrap each "block" in a `div` tag.

So for example this would be a block:

```
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1.  SOME TEXT HERE
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Some stuff
    all here
```

I figured I can use something like `.match()` or `.indexOf()` to find the "----" character that's over 5 times? And then do

```
.append( "<div>" + match + "</div>" );
```

But I realized that would wrap just the first line in a `div`. Any ideas on the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that assumes a couple things about the file coming in. I hope it's useful!

```js
function displayInDivs(str){
    const arr = str.split("\n")
    let tempString = ""
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].slice(2, 7) === "-----" && arr[i + 2].slice(2, 7) === "-----"){
            const div = document.createElement("div")
            div.innerText = tempString
            document.getElementById("output").appendChild(div)
            tempString = arr[i] + "\n"
        } else {
            tempString = tempString + arr[i] + "\n"
        }
    
    }
    const div = document.createElement("div")
    div.innerText = tempString
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(div)
    const element = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0] 
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

displayInDivs(document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent)
```

```html
<pre>
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        1.  SOME TEXT HERE
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Some stuff
        all here

    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        2. MORE TEXT HERE
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Random Stuff Here
    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        3. TITLE HERE
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        More random stuff
        they are all different lengths as well   


</pre>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Eric! Thanks so much for the quick reply,I created a quick fiddle with the code you created, doesn't seem to be working? https://jsfiddle.net/608v2erp/1/

Comment: For your fiddle, add `<div id="output"></div>` to the HTML and `displayInDivs(document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent)` to your JavaScript.

Comment: Is all the text in one giant `<pre>` tag?

Comment: Yes, it's all in one giant <pre> tag. It needs to be inside a <pre> tag so I'm thinking of removing the giant <pre> tag and then appending it inside inside of each individual div. Your updated code works amazing, once I removed the indents inside of the <pre> . Right now the <div>'s are being outputted inside of the output div. Which now causes double outputs because Its displaying the original giant <pre> and the output div. How would you recommend hiding the original <pre>

Comment: `const element = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0]`
This will select the first `pre` tag and assign it the the variable `element`. 
`element.parentNode.removeChild(element);`

Comment: Hey Eric, can you update your answer with the response you listed above to assign variable to element, this way I can check your answer as the correct answer.